# Set IFrame scrollbar to top

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe, horizontal-scrolling

I have an IFrame which I am using to horizontally scroll through a gallery.
The problem is, I would like the scrollbar to be positioned at the top.
I know this is difficult to achieve but is there any trick you can pull in either css or jQuery which can get this result?
Also I am using a .Net backend so if there are any controls which could help solve this in some other way, any ideas are appreciated.

My apologies if this has already been asked but I haven't found anything on this site yet explaining this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you control the contents of the iframe, you could use a custom jQuery scrollbar like tiny scrollbar:

http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/

You could put that inside the iframe at the top, and disable the default scrollbars on the iframe.